# Let $X$ be a normed linear space and let $V \subseteq X$ be a closed linear subspace such that $V \neq X$. Prove that $V$ is nowhere dense.

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, dense-subspaces

Is this proof right?

I approached this problem by showing that $B(x;\epsilon )$ is a subset of the complement of the closure of $V$ for all $x$ in $X$ and $\epsilon$ bigger than $0$. We know $B(x;\epsilon )= \{a \in X: d(x,a) < \epsilon \}$. Let $b \in B(x;\epsilon )$. Let us prove that $b$ is also in $(\overline{V})^c$. This would be the same as proving that $b$ is not in $\overline{V}$. Suppose $b$ would be in $\bar{V}$. This would mean that $B(x;\epsilon ) = \{b \in \overline{V}: d(x,b) < \epsilon \}$. Since $V$ is closed,  $\overline{V}=V$, and thus $b$ would be in $V$. However, by the closedness of $V$, there does not exist an epsilon neighborhoud around $V$ such that $b$ would be in an epsilon distance from $x$ (I also realize now that $x$ can be in $V$, so I am not sure what to do then?), and thus $V$ is nowhere dense.

Could anyone give a hint or advice how to look at this? It will be appreciated a lot!

Comment: No, this is not correct. The thing you're trying to prove (that $B(x,\epsilon)$ is contained in $V^c$ for any $x\in X$ and $\epsilon>0$) is clearly false, since $0\in V\cap B(0,1)$.

Comment: The particular place that your attempted proof goes wrong is that you assume that $b\in B(x,\epsilon)$. At this point, you're talking about **one fixed** $b$. But then you write $$B(x,\epsilon)=\{b\in V:d(x,b)<\epsilon\}.$$ You cannot use $b$ in the definition of $B(x,\epsilon)$, but you already have $b$ referring to a single, particular vector.

Comment: You aren't looking to show that $B(x,\epsilon)\subset V^c$. What you want to show is that for any $x\in X$ and $\epsilon>0$, $B(x,\epsilon)\cap V^c\neq \varnothing$.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback everyone. You are all completely right, and it was stupid of me to do it like this. I will give it another go. Thanks again.

Comment: Hint: Note that $V$ is a "subspace". So if $B(x,\epsilon)\subseteq V$, then $c\cdot B(x,\epsilon)\subseteq V$ for all $c\in\Bbb{R}$.